# Overload generic functions with the first generic type not in parameters

Tags: typescript, overloading, generic-type-parameters

I got a problem when using generic overload functions like below ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQIwBpFoEwB8AFFHgFy54CUFmAUKJLAsuhsTbhnQ+NPElSYc+YqQD8tarQyIAPogBucGABNEAbzoBfHqgDOUAE4wwAcxyGT54gHIMeAMy2qiAPRvEcANYMUV0zMORBDQsLCPL18DY0C7B2dXcNDIgFMjIzgjRAALdNScCABDJAB3VOQYAA9EGChEACMAT0QwOHqQfUDWAPNLWJsieycXRHE6IA)).

The generic type `T1` is not used in the parameters (just used in return type), so when I try to use overload #2, I have to provide all the types like `f<string, string>('123')` which sometimes is not possible. Is there a way to let `f<string>('123')` match `overload #2`?

```ts
function f<T1, T2>(t2: T2): T1
function f<T1>(): T1

function f<T1, T2>(t2?: T2): T1 | void {
}

f<string, string>('123') // ok
f<string>()              // ok
f<string>('123')         // error here, can we fix it by not using f<string, string>('123') ?
```

---

```ts
function f<T1, T2>(t2: T2): T1
function f<T1>(): T1

function f<T1, T2>(t2?: T2): T1 | void {
}

f < string, {id: number}>({id: 123})  // ok
f<string>()                           // ok
f<string>({id:123})                   // typescript complain here can we fix it by not using f<string, string>({id:123}) ?
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=66&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQIwBpFoEwB8AFFHgFy54CUFmAUKJLAsuhsTbhnQ%20NPElSYc%20YqQD8tarQyIAPogBucGABNEAbzoBfHsEQpEAZygAnGGADmODWopgQAWwBGAU1Pbit1RQx4AzNpUiIgA9KGIcADWDCgm5lYcIckpqWnp4ZExqPEWll52foHB6aXJmVAAngAOrkYQ5tVQiBBwjtUANgCGFogAFu6udEA)

Comment: Huh, I had thought something like `function f<T1, T2 = unknown>(t2?: T2): T1` but `f<string>('123')` treats `'123'` as `unknown` rather than `string`...

Comment: Hi, one thing I'd like to add - if this is hard to understand and perform, perhaps you shouldn't enable your code to do that, and simply change `f` into two methods that handle the code differently - this way, avoiding this issue and increasing readability

Comment: @MorShemesh, good suggestions. Actually the context is it is an optional configuration, it make sense to share the same name. But if I really cannot work out, I will choose your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a fallback for T2 to `unknown` or `any`:

```js
function f<T1, T2 = unknown>(t2: T2): T1
function f<T1>(): T1

function f<T1, T2>(t2?: T2): T1 | void {
}
```

Or simply have one declaration for all the cases:

```js
function f<T1, T2 = unknown>(t2?: T2): T1 | void {
}
// or
function f<T1, T2 = any>(t2?: T2): T1 | void {
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the type of T2 to be *inferred* from the argument. (Would have been better if the question had used different types in the usage examples, rather than `string, string`.)

Comment: Yeah, edited the response, I'm not really sure about it though

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes I want T@ to be inferred from the argument. I just updated the question. Thanks you.

Comment: This doesn't work, see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966055/typescript-overload-generic-functions-with-the-first-generic-type-not-in-parame/60966186?noredirect=1#comment107860681_60966055).

Comment: @MorShemesh, it rocks, thanks. The updated [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQIwBpFoEwC84A1mHAO5gB8AFFHgFy54CUTmiA9J4lABYBTRCTKVEMAM684iCXAA2ANwEAoUJFgJk6DLTa4MKteGjwkqTDny16Afnat2GRAB9EiuDAAmiAN4qAXyNgRBRZKAAnGDAAcxxfbyYwEABbACMBCIDaBK8mDDwAZgCWRC4eOGI1FAlI6Ji9Mqbmlta27kRKlQgEOXkBADp5OBiaVFqo2JzEguKWUpaO4GihUQBCIA)

Comment: @Ron - Hover your mouse over the `f` in the final call. It's treating the argument as `unknown`, as I said in my comment half an hour ago. It's not inferring anything.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you are totally right, this answer is not perfect. I verified it is `unknown` via this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQIwBpFoEwC84A1mHAO5gB8AFFHgFy54CUTA2pjvgLqID0-RFAAWAU0QkylRDADOwuIjlwANgDcxAKFCRYCZOgy02uDFp3ho8JKi7Na9APxN8pzIgA+iTtmZ8Aby1ERAgEOShhDEQCRAByOMQAQwUpCiQUs2DEACcxKBAcpHpEJx8oP3o+JgqtAF8LYEQUZSgcmDAAcxwAmAATJjAQAFsAIzEcutpegcQMPABmOpZ2DB4AOn6QwUQ4Yh0UCPaukxCz84vLq8udvYOjjs7p2Vn5hcRl1Y2t66udiZycByiHEeSYAHlRgArMTQWQKKAATwADhI4E00pQtEA). Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Ron There's the question of whether you really *care* that it's not inferring the type, of course. :-) I've pinged someone who knows TS really well, maybe he'll have an idea. I suspect for full-on type safety, you'll need two functions (where one of them just turns around and calls the other), but I don't know TypeScript very well yet.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I simplified the case here, and in my project `T2` is a react apollo hooks generated by graphql-codegen, which is very hard to provide explicitly. And I got a backup solution for this problem, which is to put `T1` in to parameters, this also solve it but a bit verbose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default for the type parameter, if you want `T2`  to be the same as `T1` you can use `T1` as the default:

```
function f<T1>(): T1
function f<T1, T2 extends T1 = T1>(t2: T2): T1
function f<T1, T2>(t2?: T2): T1 | void {
}

f<string, string>('123') // ok
f<string>()              // ok
f<string>('123')         // OK

f<number>(123)         // OK
```

I would like to raise a different question though. Why have `T2` at all id you don't want to specify it and just default it to `T1`. Why not just use `T1`. Type parameters that only appear in one position (either return type or a parameter type) are usually suspect. The whole point of type parameters is to establish relations between parameters or between parameters and return type.

Without knowing your full use case, this function makes more sense to me:

```
function f<T1>(): T1
function f<T1>(t2: T1): T1
function f<T1>(t2?: T1): T1 | void {
}

f<string>()              // ok
f('123')         // OK

f(123)         // OK
```

Comment: My original example is bit confusion, could you take a look this updated [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=66&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQIwBpFoEwB8AFFHgFy54CUFmAUKJLAsuhsTbhnQ+NPElSYc+YqQD8tarQyIAPogBucGABNEAbzoBfHsEQpEAZygAnGGADmODWopgQAWwBGAU1Pbit1RQx4AzNpUiIgA9KGIcADWDCgm5lYcIckpqWnp4ZExqPEWll52foHB6aXJmVAAngAOrkYQ5tVQiBBwjtUANgCGFogAFu6udEA), in which `T2` is an object. hope that make sense.